# Laravel 8 - How to relationship from 3 tables

Tags: laravel

I have 3 tables:

```
structurals
  id
  name

indicators
  id
  name

groupings
 id
 structural_id
 indicator_id
```

And Result:

```
#structural name
  indicator name
  indicator name

#structuralname
  indicator name
```

I've used method hasMany & hasManyThrough but errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, an `indicator` may belong to one or more `structural`. And a `structural` can have one or more `indicators`.

What this describes is a `many-to-many` relationship where `groupings` is only a pivot table. So you should be using the `belongsToMany` instead:

```php
class Indicator extends Model
{
    public function structurals()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Structural::class, 'groupings');
    }
}

class Structural extends Model
{
    public function indicators()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Indicator::class, 'groupings');
    }
}
```

Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

You can also remove the `id` column from the `groupings` table, as it is unnecessary.

Comment: sir, I have one question. I want add one table for insert data (id, structural_id, indicator_id, score, created_at), how to relationship that? (structural name, indicator name, score, created at) after that grouping

Comment: You can add additional columns to the pivot table and use `->withPivot()` method. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#retrieving-intermediate-table-columns

Comment: Because I will insert score everyday based on date from grouping / pivot table. according to you, it's right I'm use pivot table or create one table for insert scoring?